# Windows explorer freezes when using Open with option

Tags: windows, windows-10

Windows explorer freezes when using Open with option.Whenever I right click on any file and select Open with option, windows explorer is hanging/freezing.Need help on this.

Comment: Windows 10 you say? Well, I've seen it's a pretty buggy version of Windows. But also you may have quite a few handles, both built-in and from other apps. Also, Explorer waits for the chooser app (yes, it's a full app unlike on 7 and older!) to appear; during this wait it probably stops processing the event queue, thus getting stuck

Comment: @PaulStelian It used to work fine until yesterday, but suddenly it's behaving weird.As you said it's getting stuck while waiting, do we have any work around for this.

Comment: The OpenWith picker (which is a separate executable) may be crashing when enumerating programs.

This post might help you narrow down the offending entry. [Open With "Choose another app" Does Not Work. How to Fix it?](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/open-with-choose-another-app-does-not-work-fix/)

Comment: @w32sh: I tried both ways mentioned in the above link, but still the issue persits.

Comment: same for me. I tried all and nothing worked for me. When ever i go to open with on any image the explorer would freeze. I tried the cclean to clean registry, and tried the shexview and openwithview tools with no luck also ( i am on windows 8.1)

Answer (score 21):

I am writing this just because I was so frustrated about this, and the solutions of CCleaner and DISM didn't work for me, and I couldn't find anything online with a solution that worked.

I tried deleting the icon cache and that seemed to work for me.

Create a batch file [per these instructions](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5645-rebuild-icon-cache-windows-10-a.html) and run as admin - be aware a restart is requested and advised:

```
@echo off
set iconcache=%localappdata%\IconCache.db
set iconcache_x=%localappdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\iconcache*

echo.
echo The explorer process must be temporarily killed before deleting the IconCache.db file. 
echo.
echo Please SAVE ALL OPEN WORK before continuing.
echo.
pause
echo.
If exist "%iconcache%" goto delete
echo.
echo The %localappdata%\IconCache.db file has already been deleted.
echo. 
If exist "%iconcache_x%" goto delete
echo.
echo The %localappdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\IconCache_*.db files have already been deleted.
echo.
exit /B


:delete
echo.
echo Attempting to delete IconCache.db files...
echo.
ie4uinit.exe -show
taskkill /IM explorer.exe /F 
If exist del /A /F /Q "%iconcache%"
If exist del /A /F /Q "%iconcache_x%"
start explorer.exe
echo.
echo IconCache database files have been successfully deleted.
goto restart


:restart
echo.
echo.
echo You will need to restart the PC to finish rebuilding your icon cache.
echo.
CHOICE /C:YN /M "Do you want to restart the PC now?"
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 goto no
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto yes

:yes
shutdown /r /f /t 00

:no
exit /B
```

The [linked page](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5645-rebuild-icon-cache-windows-10-a.html) doesn't state that the icon cache causes the "open with" hang, but does state that the cache can get corrupted sometimes.

Comment: Please add the relevant information from the link to the answer itself. If the link goes dead in the future, this answer will lose a lot of its usefulness.

Comment: Worked for me. Would be good to know why (or confirm if) this is the problem, but still, happy to be operational again.

Comment: Perfect! you saved the day ^^

Comment: there is a special place  Heaven for you ...Thanks :)

Comment: When I searched for a solution, I did not expect to actually find one that would work, like is usually the case. I am still amazed.

Comment: Solved it for me as well.

Comment: THANK YOU! This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

In a [Microsoft Answers thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start-winpc/context-menu-open-with-freeze/5dec28ae-b706-4b12-ac84-3fbb71f73f68) on this, someone had good luck running CCleaner to clean up their registry. I downloaded the free version and ran it, it found a bad Open With... registry entry for an Intel utility I no longer have and never used, plus 146 more registry references to invalid paths left over from old software. I let it fix them all, and my Open with... hang is gone.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

If your system (Windows Explorer service) crashes when you right-click, that means one of the context menu options is causing an issue. It is most likely a recent software installation and an entry added by it to the context menu.

1. Launch the Event Viewer: Click the start menu and type eventvwr.msc. Press enter.
2. Go to Windows Logs > Application Logs.
3. From here, you will be able to find the crash logs. You can check for hints.
4. Although I don't want to recommend third-party software, you can use [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html). You can also use the registry but since it can be complicated, I will explain the easier option.
5. Run the ShellExView and Click Options. You want to select the following options.
   [image]
6. Now look at the existing list and also the event log and see if you can find the one with issues. You can disable all or one by one and examine the behavior. Then you will have to remove that specific menu from the context menu properly uninstalling that product/software. 
   Note: You can restart Windows Explorer by using the Options menu in the ShellExView.

Comment: I tried this. Still crashing for me! For images when ever i go to open with the explorer still freeze. I also checked my installation history and I have not installed any new applications recently! I will update this if I find a solution

Comment: You can consult the Windows event viewer to obtain the app crash details. I think the log will have a hint of the failing component other than the explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding my own answer here because I experienced this issue recently and tried many suggested things to get it working. I suspect the issue was caused by App-V applications not working correctly on the system. The solution provided [here](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/open-with-choose-another-app-does-not-work-fix/) worked for me. See the post for more details but essentially renaming `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications` in the registry resolved the issue for me as it was automatically rebuilt correctly by the OS. Insert usual warning here about doing this without backups, etc.

Answer (score -1):

1. Click “Start” or press <kbd>[image: winlogo] (Win)</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.
2. Type `cmd` and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to open an elevated command prompt (i.e., Command Prompt with admin rights). If the User Account Control dialog box appears, confirm that the action it displays is what you want, type your administrator password (if requested), and then click “Continue” (or “Yes”, if applicable).
3. Type or copy paste the below command lines into it:

   ```
   DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Scanhealth
   DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth
   sfc /scannow
   ```

Comment: @InterLinked: Does (Win)+(R) followed by (Ctrl)+(Shift)+(Enter) run a program with elevated privileges on Windows 10? Because [that doesn’t work on Windows 7](//superuser.com/q/203068/354511 "Have Windows “Run” dialog run as Admin?").

Comment: @G-Man I have no idea

Comment: @InterLinked: Then you shouldn't have edited the answer to claim that it does.

Comment: @Iftekhar: This answer would be better if you explained what those commands do, how they answer the question, what the user should look for in the output, how to tell whether the commands worked, etc. Feel free to add links to *support* your answer, but don’t just add links and say “The information is over there.”

Comment: @G-Man I don't recall editing any answers today claiming that anything worked on Windows 7. What are you talking about?

Comment: @G-Man Oh, I meant that you can either click "Start" or type "WIN+R". CTRL+Shift+Esc only works with the Start menu though. I see what you're talking about now... oops!

Comment: It's a lot easier to type (Win)(X) + a (not that this answer has anything to do with the question)

Answer (score -1):

Ran into the same issue with Win 11.
What weirdly helped me was; in file explorer (FE), View, Show - (tick/activate) File name extentions.
File extentions was showing in FE anyway, but the setting wasnt selected.
Selecting the setting to ticked, changed the OpenWith menu, which didnt freeze my pc.